# What is the word for "making something proper"

Tags: single-word-requests

I am thinking along the lines of **"normalize"** -- something like ***proper-ize***.

**-- UPDATE --**

In one of my comments, I presented an example...

> *a disorganized mess (for example, a cluttered desk) that I want to "make proper" by organizing things "properly"*

Take the above example figuratively NOT literally. An answer like "tidy up" is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: *Proper* has many different meanings. Which one are you referring to? Proper grammar? Proper manners? Proper as in societally acceptable?

Comment: Pretty much in any context, where there's something "improper" that can be "made proper". In my case, it is disorganized mess (for example, a cluttered desk) that I want to "make proper" by organizing things "properly".

Comment: You could say *rectify,* although this only works for some meanings of proper.

Comment: I don't think you have shown why "tidy up" is not what you are looking for ("tidy up" can be used figuratively and literally; even literally it can mean to bring things into order; also yes, you can 'tidy up' an improperly aligned things)

Comment: Why must one word suit all these varied contexts? This seems like  manufactured problem to me.

Comment: Actually in my context the word 'fix' makes most sense, as I said in one of the comments. But I was also interested in something which would be to "proper" what "normalize" is to "normal".

Answer (score 3):

You might consider using *organize* or *systematize*.

Answer (score 2):

How about "to clean something up"?

In an IT context, you can use something like "make something adhere to a standard".

Answer (score 2):

You can **tidy up** a cluttered desk.

Comment: But I can't tidy up an improperly aligned sewing that I might want to "make proper"

Comment: I don't think there is one word to apply in all cases. For the improperly aligned sewing the word "rectify" came to my mind, as Peter Shor writes above. It would help if you explained the exact context of the word you are looking for.

Comment: My exact context is programming. I need to sanitize some HTML content, but it is NOT typical HTML sanitization, I just want to make changes to the HTML to "make it proper" according to a set of conditions -- i.e. make it adhere to those conditions.

Comment: Then why isn't Raku's answer good enough for you? It explains exactly what you want, it just isn't a single word.

Comment: Note that [tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) is well known package that tidies up html.

Comment: @Unreason -- And, that's the reason why I don't want to use it -- because I am NOT doing exactly what tidy does.

Comment: "Standardize"? "Make compliant"?  Tbh, I think the question is so vague only "fix" would work.

Comment: @greengit, now we are getting somewhere - could you go back and edit the question and please try to explain exactly then what is the difference in meaning that you are trying to express? (In the meantime you can browse the list of synonyms for [tidy](http://thesaurus.com/browse/tidy))

Comment: Yes, I think 'fix' makes sense -- at lease in my case.

Answer (score 2):

Would **[fix](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fix)** work? Unlike [repair](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/repair), it doesn't always carry a connotation of something being *broken*, i.e. it can be used if something is merely *not quite right*.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're looking for **conform** (which you can also use figuratively):

> **conform**: to give the same shape, outline, or contour to : bring into harmony or accord 
>   *conform furrows to the slope of the land*

(Source: [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conform))